# Word String matching

Tags: r, string, stringr

i have a dataframe with two columns which are names of people. Generate the table with code below :

```
names.1=c('Ron ven goh','Phil Mick' , 'Rohan Aggarwal','John Deo Lin')
names.2=c('Rob ven goh','kitty Mol','Tejas Aggarwal','Jorge Mol Lin')
df=data.table(names.1,names.2)
```

My task is to add another variable which is binary ( Yes , No ) - if any word in the whole character string in column 1 matches any word in whole string of column 2 then "Yes" , else "No" - As long as a match is found it can give a yes.

i have this code below :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  var_customername <- strsplit(as.character(df$names.1[i]),"\\s+")
  var_relationshipname <- strsplit(as.character(df$names.2[i]),"\\s+")                                
  df$NAMEMATCH[i] <- ifelse(any(unlist(var_customername) %in% unlist(var_relationshipname)),'YES','NO')
  rm(var_customername,var_relationshipname)
}
```

My overall data frame is 7 million rows and hence it by my calculations will take 405 hours due to the if any loop - any suggestions on how this can be made faster or optimized ?

Comment: First it gave the error `Error in strsplit(filtered_household_results$CUSTOMERNAME, "\\s+") : 
  non-character argument` , then i used `as.character` in front of both the names and tried - it doesn't give the correct output - gives a Yes for all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shown a faster approach here using 'apply':

Your Approach:

```
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
+   var_customername <- strsplit(as.character(df$names.1[i]),"\\s+")
+   var_relationshipname <- strsplit(as.character(df$names.2[i]),"\\s+")                                

+   df$NAMEMATCH[i] <- ifelse(any(unlist(var_customername) %in% 
unlist(var_relationshipname)),'YES','NO')
+   rm(var_customername,var_relationshipname)
+ }
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> time.taken <- end.time - start.time
> time.taken
Time difference of 0.03119993 secs
```

My Approach:

```
> start.time <- Sys.time()
> apply(df, 1, function(x) 
ifelse(any(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[1]),"\\s+")) %in% 
unlist(strsplit(as.character(x[2]),"\\s+"))),'YES','NO'))
[1] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES"
> end.time <- Sys.time()
> time.taken <- end.time - start.time
> time.taken
Time difference of 0 secs
```

Comment: For some reason it's giving me all 'yes' using your apply approach.

Comment: got it . This is great ! time reduced from 30 seconds to 0.3 seconds on 100 rows of my data frame ! Vectorized operations in R using apply functions are the key i guess